# An exercise from Chung on $L^1$ convergence

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

One of the exercises says:

"Suppose $X_n \uparrow X$ almost surely, that each $X_n$ is integrable, and that $\sup \mathbb{E} (X_n) < \infty$. Show that $X_n \rightarrow X$ in the $L^1$ sense."

Now, if all the $X_n$ were non-negative, or if we were told that $\sup \mathbb{E} |X_n| < \infty$, this would be a trivial exercise.

But without these stronger hypotheses, I am stuck. Non of the standard theorems seem to apply (Fatou, reverse Fatou, monotone convergence), and the dominated convergence theorem doesn't apply as we aren't told a priori that the limiting variable is integrable.

This exercise also comes before uniform integrability is introduced.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: When you write $X_n \uparrow X$, do you mean $X_n$ increases to $X$?

Comment: Yes, to be completely precise, there is a null set $N$ such that for all $\omega \in \Omega \setminus N$ we have that $\lim_n X_n(\omega) = X(\omega)$ and that $X_n(\omega) \leq X_m(\omega)$ whenever $n \leq m$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $Y_n:=X_n-X_0$. Then by the initial assumptions:

- $Y_n\uparrow X-X_0$,
- $Y_n\geqslant X_0-X_0=0$ and
- $\sup_n \mathbb E[Y_n]<\infty$.

Fatou's lemma implies that $X-X_0$ is integrable. We conclude by applying the monotone convergence theorem to the sequence $(Y_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$.

Comment: An application of Scheffe's lemma is also required I believe.